# Parse get object from relation

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to get groups which is member of current User.

I tried a lot of things but parse is returning null.

```
let innerQuery = PFUser.query()
let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
innerQuery?.whereKey("objectId", containedIn: [currentUser!.objectId!])
let query = PFQuery(className: "Group")
query.orderByDescending("updatedAt")
query.whereKey("members", matchesQuery: innerQuery!) 

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (groups, error) in
            print(error)
            print(groups)
        }
```

Comment: Very hard to make out what you are trying to do.

Comment: get groups which is user already member

Comment: also I tried and members is relation
query.whereKey("members", equalTo: currentUser!)

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of the innerquery altogether and just use
    query.whereKey("members",  equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!)

Assuming you want to query for the objectId of the current user in your members class. Delete both lines with innerquery

Comment: when I use this line sometimes its returning null.

Comment: are you storing your users by objectId in your members class?  Get rid of the first 3 lines and run the rest of it. Like this: let query = PFQuery(className: "Group")
query.orderByDescending("updatedAt")
query.whereKey("members", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) 

query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (groups, error) in
            print(error)
            print(groups)
        }

Comment: in your Group table, do you have a members column that is populated by objectId's of users? If not, your query is wrong.  Typically a members table might have a column named 'objectId' that stores users objectId's, if that's the case then you need query.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().objectId) -- if the table name is "members" then swap members for Groups in the "PFQuery(className: "Members instead of groups") line

Comment: in my group table members column is relation of User class

Comment: in your group table, members column is objectId of user class?  If so, than the original code should work fine. Make sure there's data in the table, otherwise that could explain it returning null.

Comment: I'm sure there is data in the table. And memberscolumn is relation of user class. But problem is when I use query.whereKey("members", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) its sometimes not returning value.And When I use innerquery its not even returning a value

Comment: You say it's sometimes not returning. When it does return, does it return the data you expect?

Comment: For example user is in 3 group I need the show this 3 group. When I use query.whereKey("members", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) this data sometimes comes but sometimes return 0. so I'm trying to solve this problem. Also when I delete that line and fetch all groups thats coming without problem. I'm just trying to show groups which current user is in members

Comment: @muratkaya  It shouldn't behave any differently unless there's a change in the code somewhere. Maybe the Parse server went to sleep - it is not available 24 hours a day when you're using the free version...If my answer helped you please mark it as correct! :) Thank you